# Match all characters but limit to 100

Tags: regex, jmeter

A have a RegEx to match all characters in all lines like:

```
(?s)(.*)
```

But I want to **limit** it to maximum **100** characters. How can I achieve it.

**PS:** I am using this RegEx in Jmeter to process the response body of an HTTP request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match *up to 100* any characters, use a `{0,100}` [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
(?s)(.{0,100})
```

This will be working if you have a default `$1$` template.

By the way, you do not need a capturing group, you may use `(?s).{0,100}` and then a `$0$` template to reference the whole match value.

Comment: Note that you may avoid getting empty strings if you use `{1,100}` quantifier. The `1` argument is the lower bound and `100` is the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution. I used this:

**((?s).{100})**

Comment: If the text has fewer than 100 chars, this will not yield a match. Is that really what you need? Then please edit the question. Please see my answer.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I need to get characters even it is less than 100. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I posted an answer with the exact solution.